# Modal with PHP, SQL & AJAX METHOD

Tags: php, sql, modal-dialog

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code? I'm trying to update my SQL depending on the username with modal form. I need to have a modal popup in every row and update a specific user based on their username.

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
function build_table($result){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo "<table class='tbl'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Username</th>";
        echo "<th>User type</th>";
        echo "<th>Status</th>";
        echo "<th>Created by</th>";
        echo "<th>Change Status</th>";
        echo "<th>Actions</th>";
        echo "</tr><br>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['usertype'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['createdby'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<a data-toggle='modal' id='up_modal' href = '#myModal' data-username = '". $row['username'] . "'>Activate </a>";
  ?>
```

Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Activate Account</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="showcal"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's for the js function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       var username = $("#up_modal").attr('data-username')
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url:'activate-account.php?username='+username,
                success:function(data){
                    $('#showcal').html(data);
                }
         });
     });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: May I ask why are you using a modal for this. Can you simply do a GET request to the url? But if it has to be a modal what are the codes for the modal.

Comment: Well, you are hardcoding the username in the AJAX action. So you either a) have one JS script with the last value of `$row['username']` or b) multiple scripts with the same event handler attached to it. Please add more details about your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the wrong when trying to get a username `url:'activate-account.php?username='+'<?php echo $row['username'];?>',` by using PHP query
In Ajax request, you can give the anchor tag specific id and put the username value in new attribute like the following code

```
echo "<a data-toggle='modal' id='up_modal' href = '#myModal' data-username = '".<?php echo $row['username'];?>."'>Activate </a>";
```

and In JavaScript get the value by the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       var username = $("#up_modal").attr('data-username')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:'activate-account.php?username='+username,
            success:function(data){
            $('#showcal').html(data);
         }
       });
    });
});
```

Or you can get it by query string as you did in anchor tag you pass username as a query string so you can do the following code In js function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
       var url_string = window.location.href
       var url = new URL(url_string);
       var username = url.searchParams.get("username");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:'activate-account.php?username='+username,
            success:function(data){
            $('#showcal').html(data);
         }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: the 2nd js function is working but its gives a null result for the username :(

Comment: The 2nd function I made depends on what you pass, you can pass the username In different ways depending on the structure of your coding I don't know if there's many users or this page just for one user if this page for many users, you can make id depend on the user_id and use it to get what ever the value you want